# Google App Engine ndb query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created an Entity, called "Event" in the Google Cloud Datastore for my project. The entity has an ID generated by AppEngine followed by two properties

- Location
- Date

I am trying to query this entity by its ID (5629499534213120), so , here is my code.

```
    key = 5629499534213120
    e = Event.get_by_id(key)
    logging.info("Event Location = %s" % e.Location)
```

The value of e is NoneType.

code

```
   __author__ = 'vinayjoseph'

from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import logging


class Event(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual event at xxx xxxx """
    Date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    Location = ndb.StringProperty()


def get_meeting_date():
    """gets the next meeting date from the No SQL Schemaless Google Datastore
    """
    key = 5629499534213120
    e = Event.get_by_id(key)
    logging.info("Event Location = %s" % e.Location)
```

e is NoneType

In the datastore I see the following at 
https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~xxxxx/datastore/editentity?key=xxxxx%2FEvent%20id:5629499534213120

[image: screen shot of the entity in the datastore]

I suspect the problem might be with my key.

When I try to query the datastore in development using dev_appserver.py it works. I am using a different key for dev.

```
def get_meeting_date():
    """gets the next meeting date from the No SQL Schemaless Google Datastore
    """
    #dev
    key = 6401356696911872
    #prd
    #key = 5629499534213120
    e = Event.get_by_id(key)
    logging.info("Event Location = %s" % e.Location)
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding quotes around the ID event_key = ndb.Key("Event", "5629499534213120")

Comment: ID should be int int, so that should be fine.  Does this entity have a parent entity?

Comment: Tried both and it did not work And no it does not have a parent entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I finally figured it out.

I had to make a few changes to the entity itself, just to get the filtering right. So the new properties are as seen below.
[image: Entity Properties]

The code in python is as follows:

```
__author__ = 'vinayjoseph'

from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import logging
from datetime import datetime

class Event(ndb.Model):
    """Models an individual event at xxx xxx """
    Date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    Location = ndb.StringProperty()
    Address = ndb.StringProperty()
    Name = ndb.StringProperty()


def get_meeting_date():
    """gets the next meeting date from the No SQL Schemaless Google Datastore
    """
    qry = Event.query(Event.Name == 'Next Meeting Location')
    for event in qry.fetch(1):
        logging.info("Meeting is on %s at %s" % (str(event.Date), event.Address))
```

And it works like a charm. Check out the log entry in app-engine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the query method, you're using ancestor. If your entities have a parent, then you have to include it in the get_by_id call.

Comment: Yes, however I am not using this method anymore. The event var is of type NoneType in the get_meeting_date() method.